# Do Americans remove the "t" in "wanted"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, consonants

When you pronounce the phrase "I got a message you wanted to see me", is the "t" usually deleted in the word "wanted"? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect this usage is specifically affected by the fact that it's exceptionally common for *all* native speakers (not just AmE) to say things like *You're **gonna wanna** see this!* in casual speech (where what's *really* being elided in both cases is primarily the /t/ of ***to***). Off-hand I can't think of any other cases where /nt/  the middle of a word reduces to just /n/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is such a *tendency*, but it varies in degree regionally, and the vowel involved will also have an effect on the degree of inarticulation. The lower the vowel before the nasal, the less articulate the dental. With high front vowels, e.g. **hinted**, the dental is likely to be articulated more forcefully than it would be with low back vowels, **haunted**.

Speakers native to my area of the country (mid-Atlantic) still place the tongue as if to produce the dental; it's only the degree of the plosiveness which changes. Speakers native to the south are more likely not to position the tongue forward for the dental; it would remain pretty much where it had been when producing the preceding nasal.

If you listen to how southerners and northerners say the word **haunted**, you'll notice that the southerners produce the vowel lower and farther to the back, and this tends to move the entire apparatus back. Thus they would have a little more "distance" to travel to produce an articulate dental than a northerner would.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed more and more lately that Americans, at least in my region, do tend to *elide* t's in the middles of words. Thus, "Martin" becomes "Mar-uhn", "wanted" becomes "wan-ned", and "Atlanta" becomes "Atlanna". :-(

**EDIT**
I have a French friend who as observed to me that Americans in general tend to let t's in the middles of words go soft. I add this because she has visited other parts of the country, and she comes to it with an outsider's ear.

Comment: "wan-ned" and "Atlanna" sound right to me, but I think that's a glottal stop in the middle of "Martin", not elision. In your region is it pronounced without the stop?

Comment: @DanGetz I have heard both: the elision in general conversation and the glottal stop from a correspondent on the local "Atlanna" news (wince!).

Comment: It's not a complete elision, however. I guess I do say "Martin" not as /mar'tʰɪn/, but as /mar'ṇ̃/, where the /ṇ̃/ is a syllabic nasal cosonant with the underside of the toungue against the back of the hard palate; but that's still different from how I would say a hypothetical word *marrin, /mar'ṇ/, a syllabic nasal consonant with the tip of the toungue against the bottom of the hard palate. I say that name differently in Spanish, /martin'/. And in my U.S. accent "Atlanta" is a homophone for the girl's name "Alana", but I say it  /at͡ɬan'ta/ in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Pronouncing that phrase at normal speed (especially that particular phrase, as a quick way to get someone's attention), yes the "t" would be dropped. But it may be helpful to explore some of the other changes in that sentence, and similar ones.

> "I got a message you wanted to see me" → /ai' gã: mes'əʒ yu waɛ̃u si' mi/

Note the /waɛ̃u/ here; that's "wanted to", no standard contraction but somehow collapsed to a *single unstressed syllable* with a big dipthong, nasalised in the middle but not the beginning or end. Likewise "got a" is collapsed to a single unstressed syllable with an unemphasized double-lenghth nasalized vowel.  (And I tend to say "I am going to", written very infomally as "I'm gonna", as /aĩ gʌ̃/.)

> "I got a message that you wanted to see me", said more slowly for emphasis → /ai gatʰ ʌ me'səʒ ðæt yu wantʰɪd tʰu si:' mi:/, or ... /si: mi:'/

This would be understood as the same words. I might say "got" as /gaɂ/ (ending in a glottal stop) rather than /gatʰ/ even in this expanded form.

> "I got a message you want to see me" → /ai gã: mes'əʒ yu wã: si' mi/

This might not be grammatically correct?  And I'm not sure I'd her the differnce reliably.

> "I got a message you won't see me" → /ai gã: mes'əʒ yu wõ'ɂ si mi/

Opposite meaning, only difference the quality of that one vowel.

> "I got a message you can see me" → /ai gã: mes'əʒ yu kṇ si' mi/, or ... /yu kæ:n' si me/ (/ṇ/ represents a short syllabic "n")

Different emphasis in the two altrnatives, one a general statement, the other a contradiction of a previous understanding.

> "I got a message you can't see me" → /ai gã: mes'əʒ yu kæ̃'ɂ si' mi/

Once again, an opposite meaning, only difference the quality of the vowel in one syllable.  A native speaker wanting to be more clear would be more likely to expand the contraction to "cannot" /kæn'at/ or "can not" /kæ:n nat'/ instead of fully enunciating the contraction /kæntʰ/.